# Value from onSubmit prompt to PHP GET

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a modifypassword form that modifys the password in a flat file for a user.( I know its not safe etc. ).

So the thing is: whenever I click on modify password on my website, I get a prompt that asked to enter a new password. All fine, after that it will submit the form. But I cannot get the variable somehow that is typed in. I want to $_GET['newpw'] so I can use it to adjust my flat file.

So I have a form like this:

```
echo "<td> <form action=\"admin.php\" method=\"GET\" onsubmit=\" modifyPassword();\">
```

this is the modifyPassword function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function modifyPassword() {
        var newpw=prompt("Enter a new password");
        if(newpw !== null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "admin.php",
                data: {data: newpw},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

And when the form is actually submitted I want to get the value from what is typed in like this:

```
echo $_GET['data'];
```

This is all in the same file.
The output of $_GET['data'] does not show anything.
The rest just works fine when I choose a static password like: "test".  It will update my flat file, but I want to get the user input to change the password.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the PHP code that handles the request?

Comment: }elseif (isset($_GET['Modify'])){

        echo $_GET['data'];  // also tried 'newpw'

Comment: Well... $_GET['Modify'] isn't set in that request so it would never happen

Comment: you are `sending` data so use $_GET['data'].

Comment: Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the base problem may be, that you have event handler onsubmit, but the form gets submited anyway. So the actual prompt has no chance to execute.

You should add `return false;` or manage the logic in `modifyPassword()` method.

For example this may help to stop form to submit:
`echo "<td> <form action=\"admin.php\" method=\"GET\" onsubmit=\"modifyPassword(); return false;\">"`

**OR**

If you want to submit the form in standard way, just to change the password, just change the input value.

Modify form: `echo "<td> <form action=\"admin.php\" method=\"GET\" onsubmit=\"modifyPassword(this)\"><input type=hidden name=newpw />"`

And then change the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function modifyPassword(passForm)
        {
            var newpw = prompt("Enter a new password");
            if (newpw !== null)
            {
                passForm.newpw.value = newpw;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Then you should have the value in php in `$_GET['newpw']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current PHP code:

```
}elseif (isset($_GET['Modify'])){ echo $_GET['data'];
```

But according to the Ajax request code, you don't send a `Modify` parameter so the `$_GET['Modify']` isn't set and therefore the condition returns `false` and never reach to the `echo $_GET['data']` part.

You need to add another parameter to the `data` as in the following:

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function modifyPassword(){

                            var newpw=prompt("Enter a new password");
                            if(newpw !== null){
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "GET",
                                    url: "admin.php",
                                    data: {action: 'modifypass', data: newpw}, //Added another parameter.
                                    success: function(data)
                                    {
                                        console.log(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }}
                        </script>
```

**PHP**

```
 elseif (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "modifypass"){
    echo $_GET['data'];
```

Comment: Maybe i dont understand your answer clearly, but it does reach the echo statement, its just empty. I also have other code in the elseif isset modify. That gets executed. For example: this gets executed when i submit: echo $_GET['data'] . " <--- new password";  And also other lines beneath this code. Because right now it does modify the password to "test" but i want to modify the password by user input